# Basic question about conditional expectation and $\sigma$-fields

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty.$ Let $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ be a couple of $\sigma$-algebras.

The towering property states that:

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]|\mathcal{G}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{F}] = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]~.$$

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a $\sigma$-field that is independent of $\mathcal{F}.$ Then, how may I prove the following statement?

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]|\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}] =\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}].$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that
$$
\Bbb E[\Bbb E[X|\mathcal F]1_G1_H]=\Bbb E[\Bbb E[X|\mathcal G]1_G1_H]
\tag{*}
$$
for all $G\in\mathcal G$ and $H\in\mathcal H$. (This is because $1_G1_H=1_{G\cap H}$, and $\{G\cap H:G\in\mathcal G,H\in\mathcal H\}$ is a $\pi$-system generating $\sigma(\mathcal G,\mathcal H)$.) Now use the fact that $\Bbb E[X|\mathcal F]1_G$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, and the independence of $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal H$, to show that left side of ($*$) is
$$
\Bbb E[[\Bbb E[X|\mathcal F]1_G]\cdot\Bbb P[H],
$$
which is in turn equal to (use the Tower Property here)
$$
\Bbb E[[\Bbb E[X|\mathcal G]1_G]\cdot\Bbb P[H].
$$
Evaluate the left side of ($*$) in like fashion to arrive at the same expression.